# Hessian matrix = zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hessian-matrix

Is there something we can tell about the function, if we know that its Hessian matrix is the zero matrix? Is it concave, convex? What about quasi-concave and quasi-convex? As I am a beginner on this topic, I would be interested, if there's maybe an intuitive answer to this. Thanks!

Comment: If at a point, then no, you can’t say much. Even in one dimension, there are crazy things a function can do yet have the second derivative vanish at a point. Actually, since bump functions exist, you see that all sorts of crazy stuff can happen. So if you want a more definitive answer, you’re going to have to be more specific with what assumptions you’re willing/wish to impose.

Comment: If it's zero in its entire domain, surely it's a linear transformation, right? I might have not understood the question correctly.